# Javascript SignalR wait until service broadcasted all messages

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, signalr, wait

I have a for loop on a list of objects, where on some condition on these objects i need to call the signal-r function to load some data for each object.
And after all these objects are filled with the returned data from the hub, i want to continue a process on client side.

My problem is i want to be able to track that all the loop is completed and then continue the rest of the code.

```
var stratsList = new Array();

for (var cp = 0; cp < myPools.length; cp++) {
    if (myPools.SubItems.length == 0)
        conn.server.LoadData(myPools[cp].id);

    $.each(myPools.SubItems, function (k, v) {
        stratsList.push(v.name);
    });
}

for (var s = 0; s < stratsList.length; s++) {
    //Do some other work once all SubItems on myPools are Loaded.
}
```

So, basically while looping on myPools, i am checking SubItems of each myPools has data loaded.
If not loaded, i want to load data and then continue.

When you call a signal-r function, the reply comes into another function. So i donno how to keep track.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm relatively new to JavaScript, but I'll take a crack at this.

```
var numPoolsToBeFilled = myPools.length;

var doMoreWorkIfReady = function () {
    if (numPoolsToBeFilled <= 0) {
        for (var s = 0; s < stratsList.length; s++) {
            // Do some other work once all SubItems on myPools are Loaded.
        }
    }
};

for (var cp = 0; cp < myPools.length; cp++) {
    if (myPools.SubItems.length == 0)
        conn.server.LoadData(myPools[cp].id);
    else
        numPoolsToBeFilled--;
}
// ... other code omitted ...

// just in case all pools were already filled
doMoreWorkIfReady();
```

Then inside your reply/callback function...

```
numPoolsToBeFilled--;
doMoreWorkIfReady();
```

I don't know how your code is organized, so you'd have to figure out where to put numPoolsToBeFilled and doMoreWorkIfReady such that both the loading function and the reply function have access to them.

Comment: Amazing... THANK YOU SO MUCH. you solution is PERFECT :)